# C++ exception thrown inside constructor member initializer?

Tags: c++, exception, c++11, constructor

Consider the following situation:

```
struct X { ... };

struct Y
{
     Y(...);

     ...

     X x;

     ...
}

X f()
{
    ...

    if (...)
        throw E;

    ...
}

Y::Y(...) :
    ... ,
    x(f()) ,
    ...
{
    ...
}
```

Is there any undefined behaviour here?  Are there any gotchas or potential problems with such a design when E is thrown?

**Update:**

`Y::x` may not be the only member variable of `Y`, may not be the first member variable in the class, and may be initialized half way through the `Y::Y` init list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any undefined behaviour here?

No. The construction of `Y` is aborted.

> Are there any gotchas or potential problems with such a design when E is thrown?

No `Y` is ever created, so there is no destructor to call. Destructors for fully constructed elements, those declared before `x` in the class body, will be called automatically (how would you otherwise know how far the initialization list you were when it throw). If you need to destroy anything, then you must catch the exception and destroy it yourself. You cannot absorb the exception, you can rethrow it, throw a new exception, or do nothing which will result in the exception being rethrown anyway. For your particular use case, there shouldn't be anything to destroy since the constructor body is not going to be invoked at all.

Comment: He only has to destroy whatever was *not* a member *and* requires manual destruction- which, in the mem init list, is usually and should be nothing.

Comment: Question: what is "everything else"? The body of the constructor of `Y` is not going to be invoked at all and `x` is the first member in the class definition so no other variable has been initialized before `x`

Comment: You don't necessarily have to _catch_ the exception in order to correctly handle destroying things. The constructor simply needs to be exception safe like every other function.

Comment: I've made a slight modification sorry:  x may not be the only member and may be half way through the init list.

Comment: @AndrewTomazosFathomlingCorps: members are initialized in the order they appear in the class definition. Is `x` the first member variable in your class definition? It seems so

Comment: @AndyProwl: Fixed, thanks.  `x` may not be the first member.  There may be many before and many after.

Comment: To clarify:  If any members where constructed before x, is it the compilers responsibility to call their destructors?

Comment: @AndrewTomazosFathomlingCorps: yes i think the compiler will call the destructors, but that might not save you if your member variables previously constructed acquired resources without using RAII (e.g. naked pointers initialized with the result of a call to `new` - but again, that is bad design)

Comment: @AndyProwl: So the member variables would have their destructors called but `Y`s destructor will not be called.  So if a member was a `std::unique_ptr<T>` it would be ok, but for a `T*` it would not be ok because that manual deletion is in Ys destructor.

Comment: @AndrewTomazosFathomlingCorps: exactly like you said.

Answer (score 2):

When an exception is throwing during the construction of an object, the destructors of all fully constructed subobjects are called. That is, assuming your type `X` throwing an exception correctly cleans up any resources it may have allocated before the exception was thrown, there is no issue.

Comment: Destructors having to be called in reverse order of construction is the underlying reason.

Comment: I don't see the connection in the second paragraph.  Why would the clean-up procedure be different if the members were initialized in constructor init list order instead of class definition order?

Comment: OK, I'll remove the second paragraph.